# Why Microsoft doesn't use async/await in source code?

Tags: c#, performance, asynchronous, async-await, task

In [this link](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/51cf7850defa8a17d815b4700b67116e3fa283c2/System/net/System/Net/Http/HttpClient.cs#L322) I can see the implementation of the [`HttpClient.PutAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.putasync) method:

```cs
public Task<HttpResponseMessage> PutAsync(Uri requestUri, HttpContent content,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Put, requestUri);
    request.Content = content;
    return SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
}
```

Microsoft does not use the `async/await` in most methods.

I have two question:

1. When we can remove `async/await` keyword?
2. Does eliding `async/await` effect on the performance?

Comment: What for? `SendAsync` is also returns `Task<HttpResponseMessage>` ... async build state machine at compile time ... if you don't needed you should not use it ... in this example you don't need as there is only one call to asyncmethod, it is at the end and it returns the same type

Comment: [Eliding Async and Await](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html) by Stephen Cleary

Comment: also https://youtu.be/zhCRX3B7qwY

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain It means I should use `async/await` when I need to get response from a task and doing something?
For example in API level, I can remove `async/await`?

Comment: It's a bit more complex. Best is to see the link from Stephen, indeed.

Comment: [Here is an example](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/v7.0.0/src/libraries/System.Threading.Channels/src/System/Threading/Channels/ChannelReader.cs#L77) of Microsoft code that uses `async`. It's from the implementation of the [`ChannelReader<T>.ReadAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.channelreader-1.readasync) API. Asking why Microsoft opted to use `async` or elide `async` in each and every case, is a question both too broad and opinion-based. If you really want to know, you'd better ask directly Microsoft's software engineers on GitHub.

Comment: For performance (await is a possible pause point), Microsoft has the developers to write safe code, you on the other hand better use await, case most likely you are not good at writing thread safe code :p